# Browser-sync only fires once with nodemon + gulp + express

Tags: javascript, express, gulp, browser-sync, nodemon

**After looking for loads of related questions, I could not find the correct answer that fits my needs.**

So I'm running an Express server and I'd like to automate some tasks using Gulp.
It's very basic, as all I need is restarting the server (using Gulp-nodemon) and then reload the browser on file changes (using Browser-sync for cross-browser and multiple device debugging).

When I run my `gulp start` command, the server starts and so does Browser-sync which opens my page properly.
However, on file changes, nodemon is properly restarting the server but browser-sync's reload does not trigger. I need then to refresh manually the page to see the changes...

Here's my gulpfile :

```
//Some requires

gulp.task('css', function () {
    gulp.src('stylus/main.styl')
        .pipe(stylus({compress: false, paths: ['stylus']}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(rename('style.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/styles'));
});

gulp.task('sync', ['nodemon'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: 'http://localhost:3000',// Don't use proxy
        port: 4000, // Desired PORT address.
        open: true,
        notify: true,
        logConnections: true,
        reloadDelay: 1000
    });
});

gulp.task('nodemon', function (cb) {
    var started = false;
    return nodemon({
        script: 'index.js',
        tasks: ['css'],
        ext: 'js ejs styl', 
        env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development' }
    }).on('start', function() {
        if (!started) {
            cb();
            started = true;
            browserSync.reload();
        } 
    }).on('restart', function() {
    });
});

gulp.task('start', ['sync']);
```

Is there anything I'm missing ?

I saw there are lots of questions on this point, but everyone seems to encounter issues at very different stages...

Comment: Usually the 'css' task would have .pipe(reload({ stream:true })); at the end, but perhaps nodemon takes care of that for you.  Anyway, I would try adding the stream:true option into your 'nodemon' task reload() call.

Comment: @Mark as nodemon takes care of the CSS task, the reload there is useless, as the app has not restarted yet. I also already tried the stream: true in the initial reload call, no effect.